# C# read custom configuration build

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

In my .net application, I have added new build modes for the configurations.

I currently have: Debug, Release, BetaDebug & BetaRelease.
Each having a specific purpose for software engineering purposes.

I wish to know if I can get a C# string containing this text. So I can then do:

```
string configurationBuild = GetConfigurationBuild();

if(configurationBuild.Contains("Beta") {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: You considered preprocessor commands testing for the build modes and setting a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure that each configuration will define Conditional Compilation symbols  use preprocessor instructions like #if to find out which build configurationis being used.
Here is a link on msdn forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d574468-c890-49d2-984e-16ad068a006e/build-configuration-in-preprocessor

Comment: Is there a way to get this dynamically, i.e. if I added later a new mode (like Release Candidate), I will be able to get it without modification.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to change the proprocessor instructions as you add new configurations, as preprocessor instructions are not the .net code, they are statically interpeted at compile time

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional compilation symbols ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS.PROJECTPROPERTIESBUILD);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true ) for your build modes.

In your code you can then use the #if directive http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.100).aspx